# How to make a procedural road network using geo nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I'm trying to get a system where I can draw a road using Bezier curves, then having geo nodes do magic to connect the roads at intersections.

this is what i came up with
[image]
and it turns this curve
[image]
into this
[image]

now, a couple of problems

1. at all intersections the points connect in the middle leaving overlapping polygons
2. I want to have control over the curve at the intersections, possibly using the weight or radius of the control point, like this for example [image]
   [image]